# Access resources of app from library

Tags: android, reflection, resources, android-library

Is it possible to access data of the res folder from within the library project, the app is including?

I tried to use reflection, but I can only access the res data of the library itself when I call it from the lib.

```
    Field[] fields = R.drawable.class.getFields();
    int size = fields.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Field field = fields[i];
        try {
            int resID = field.getInt(null);
            Drawable drawable= context.getResources().getDrawable(resID);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It only gets the files from app if there are already files with the same name in the lib project.

The reason why I need it is I want to give the users the possibility to include the lib and simply doing one method call without the need of rewriting the reflection code by themselves.

Comment: do you have a "main project" and a library. Do you want to use  the resources of the library in the "main project" ?

Comment: provide a general resource in your library project and override it in your application  (Overriding  = same filename). When the application is build the first occurrence of that resource will be used (the one in your  application and not the library)

Comment: @blackbelt nope, exactly the other way round

Comment: @user1281750 This doesn´t make sense in my case, because it shouldn´t limit the user and I do not know what resources he will have

Comment: you are requiring a resource, so your are limiting the developer using your libary. Simple action -> reaction logic to me. And note about the rewriting the reflection code? they need to provide a resource thats all. while they are implmention your lib they will notice that a resource from the lib is used. Developers will notice this and will override or replace that resource.

Comment: Okay, lets say the user has images stored in his app and has included my library. Now I want the library the retreive these images, without the need of the users action of telling the library what images he has( Because it´s not solvable in a single line, it needs a bit of code).There is no exact resource, the library requires, I want simply access all resources from the library, no matter what they are and how many they are. Hope its a bit more clearly now

Comment: Why not let the user hand your lib his `Resources` and `R`?

Comment: Hmm, than he has to either implement reflection by himself or pass all resources manually. Maybe, this is really the only solution to go for